# Push enter button inside an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have the following code:

```
var analogSearch = $('#dataTableAnalog_filter :input').val();
var digitalSearch = $('#dataTableDigital_filter :input').val();
```

in order to get the value from an input

Afterwards, I use:

```
    var analogSearchInput = $('#dataTableAnalog_filter :input');
    var digitalSearchInput = $('#dataTableDigital_filter :input');
    analogSearchInput.val(analogSearch);
    digitalSearchInput.val(digitalSearch);
```

To re-enter the data to the input. And I would like to click enter in each input in order to filter a DataTable. Is that possible?

Comment: `$('input').on('keydown', function(e) {if (e.which==13) dataTable(); })`

Comment: I do not want an event handler. I would like to click enter inside the input programmatically.

Comment: Sure, `$('input').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {which: 13}));`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It should work, but maybe you'll have to use keycode instead of which, and it's generally not a very good idea IMO to trigger a keypress to trigger an event to trigger a function, when you can just call the function directly ?

Comment: I would find the event handler for the DataTable and fire that manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#inputId').on('keydown', function(event) {

    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
     //Do Something Here...Submit Maybe?
    }   

});
```